# Set delay before an e-mail is marked as read in iPad Mail

Tags: ios, ipad, mail.app

In iPad Mail app, as soon as an e-mail is displayed it is marked as read. Is it possible to set a delay (e.g. 5 seconds) before it is marked as read?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? It would be helpful to explain, thanks.